# How do I merge multiple dictionaries values having same key in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, dictionary

I have n number of dicts like this :

```
dict_1 = {1: {'Name': 'xyz', 'Title': 'Engineer'}, 2: {'Name': 'abc', 
         'Title': 'Software'}}
dict_2 = {1: {'Education': 'abc'}, 2: {'Education': 'xyz'}}
dict_3 = {1: {'Experience': 2}, 2:{'Experience': 3}}
.
.
.
dict_n
```

I just want to combine all of them based on main key like this :

```
final_dict = {1: {'Name': 'xyz', 'Title': 'Engineer', 'Education': 
            'abc', 'Experience': 2}, 
             2: {'Name': 'abc', 'Title': 'Software', 'Education': 
            'xyz', 'Experience': 3}}
```

can anybody help me to achieve this ?

Comment: We help you solving the errors in your code. No code, no errors for us to solve.

Comment: what you tried?

Comment: Tagging `python-3.x` _and_ `python-2.7` doesn't help identify what version of Python you are asking about.

Comment: I was looking for the solution, I need the code snippet to achieve that final_dict

Answer (score 0):

from your question I think you have n number of dicts. So make list of your dicts and combine all the values having same key. 
But that itself won't give the exact answer. They are list of dicts. So the second thing I have done is make all those small dicts to one dict .

Here my code you can check :

```
d1 = {1: {'Name': 'xyz', 'Title': 'Engineer'}, 2: {'Name': 'abc', 
  'Title': 'Software'}}
d2 = {1: {'Education': 'abc'}, 2: {'Education': 'xyz'}}
d3 = {1: {'Experience': 2}, 2:{'Experience': 3}}

ds = [d1, d2, d3] # list of your dicts you can change it to dict_

big_dict = {}
for k in ds[0]:
   big_dict[k] = [d[k] for d in ds]

for k in big_dict.keys():
    result = {}
    for d in big_dict[k]:
        result.update(d)
    big_dict[k] = result
print(big_dict)
```

It gives O/P like this :

```
{
1: {'Education': 'abc', 'Title': 'Engineer', 'Name': 'xyz', 
   'Experience': 2}, 
2: {'Education': 'xyz', 'Title': 'Software', 'Name': 'abc', 
   'Experience': 3}
}
```